# Remove All html tag except one tag

Tags: c#, regex

I have some code to remove all html tag but I want to remove all html but except `</td>` and `</tr>` tags.

How can this be done?

```
public string HtmlStrip( string input)
{
    input = Regex.Replace(input, "<input>(.|\n)*?</input>", "*");
    input = Regex.Replace(input, @"<xml>(.|\n)*?</xml>", "*"); // remove all <xml></xml> tags and anything inbetween.  
    return Regex.Replace(input, @"<(.|\n)*?>", "*"); // remove any tags but not there content "<p>bob<span> johnson</span></p>" becomes "bob johnson"
}
```

Comment: just remembered http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1283124

Comment: saw that but don;t understand...

Comment: @IlyaIvanov Reminded me of the exact same thing. OP, using regex to parse HTML is a dangerous venture. You should use some other method (like representing your HTML as XML) instead.

Comment: So you want to remove all HTML except for two _closing_ tags? What about the opening tags (e.g. `<td>` and `<tr>`)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: I want to remove opening tag also..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Regex is not great for parsing XML or HTML. Take a look at the HTML Agility Pack

[HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples)

Comment: A longer answer is not needed!

Answer (score 0):

remove all tag html but except tag td and tr

input = Regex.Replace(input, @"<(?!td|/td|tr|/tr).*?>", "");

Comment: Use the code formatting feature for better readability. Explain what is the purpose of the code you mentioned in the context of your question.